# Design an algorithm to input 2 numbers and then output the lowest number in little man computing

Tags: algorithm, little-man-computer

I have a program I'm doing and I want to input two numbers so that the LMC can output the smallest one. MY code is giving me the biggest number, help me fix it.

```
INP
STA first
INP
STA second

SUB second
BRP secondBig
LDA second
OUT
BRA endProgram
secondBig LDA second
OUT
endProgram HLT
first DAT
second DAT
```

Comment: Fixing simple problems like this yourself is a much better way of *learning* than just copying someone else's solution. If your goal is to learn.

Comment: Or at least find someone better to copy from :)

Comment: As Scott Hunter already pointed out, you're printing the second value in both branches.  Also note that you're testing **second - second**, which will not give you any useful information.  Please give us the pseudo-code you are trying to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're storing both input values in `first`, which means you overwrite the first one with the second.

Both before and after fixing the above, your code isn't outputting the biggest, it is outputting the *second* (regardless of relative size).  Single-stepping, or actually reading the code, should tell you why.

Comment: sorry, it was a mistake please check the code again

Answer (score 0):

Invert your conditional branch: use BRN (branch negative) instead of BRP.
Alternately, switch the logic branches that decide which value will be available for output.

Comment: Okay let me try that

Comment: program halted at BRN, is it possible to rewrite the code for me

Comment: `BRN` isn't a valid instruction.

Comment: you said branch negative

Comment: My mistake -- wrong instruction set.  I'll correct the answer when you clarify the problem (see comment on the posting).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that you compared the second input with itself. You could insert `LDA first` just before `SUB second`, but if you invert the output blocks, you can avoid that extra `LDA`

It is also confusing that you have a label "secondBig", when in fact you are not looking for the biggest number, but the smallest

Correction:

```html
#input: 4 7
           INP
           STA first
           INP
           STA second

           SUB first
           BRP firstLeast

           LDA second     
           OUT
           BRA endProgram
           
firstLeast LDA first
           OUT
           
endProgram HLT

first      DAT
second     DAT

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/trincot/lmc@v0.7/lmc.js"></script>
```